# How can I search a word in any order in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find rows that match the search word in any order?

If the search is "1234"

match found like "1234" , "4321',"2314","3412"

but NOT include like "12345","123", "2214"

========================================================================

As Chris mentioned, I think using LEN(table.search) is helpful. 
Search word can be anything, the expected result(I'm hoping to get) should be same number of characters but each characters can be in any order.  
for ex) if search word is "abc1dx", 
 
the result can include "abc1dx", "1abcdx", "xd1abc", "dxabc1". 
 
however words like "abc1dx1", "aac1dx" should NOT be inclueded

Comment: Don't. Use a processing language like PHP instead.

Comment: Are those real and complete examples? if not, add a bigger set -with real size of word- and expected results

Comment: if you have to create such search engine you have a trouble! :) read about sphinx

Comment: many letters have your biggest word to find?

Comment: What about search strings size. is it always have same length??

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have to have a `WHERE` clause that includes all of those permutations.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    table.search='1234' OR 
    table.search='4321' OR 
    table.search='1423' ... 
    etc
```

As you can see, you're going to have a rather huge query; in fact much larger as your search term length grows. **This is a bad way of doing it.**

Another option could be to make a query to find results with any of the characters with a LIKE query and where the length matches:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE
    table.search LIKE '%1%' AND
    table.search LIKE '%2%' AND
    table.search LIKE '%3%' AND
    table.search LIKE '%4%' AND
    LEN(table.search) = 4
```

This is better, and will be ok as long as you don't have any duplicate values in your search term (like "12321") - it'll run into problems there.

As pointed out in the comments, you're probably better off just doing a more general query and using a different technique for getting the matches.

Comment: OMG. "1234" was just example. search word can be random size word.

Comment: It could be like "jason" then ("ajons","nosaj") any order

Comment: I understand. 1234 is just an example to match your question. You can replace the values with anything, your query will just grow larger for each new character. This will be fine unless you're encountering words with duplicate characters in them, at which point you'll need to process the results after the query (as pointed out in the comments above).